# Does the top-level value in JSON have to be an array or object?

Tags: json, standards

This object literal is valid JSON:

```
{ "foo" : "bar"}
```

And so is this array literal:

```
["foo", "bar", 1, 2, 3, null]
```

But what about a string by itself?

```
"foo"
```

Or a number by itself?

```
 0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recent JSON specs ([RFC 7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159) Mar 2014, and [ECMA-404](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf)) define a JSON text as optional whitespace surrounding any JSON value, where a value is any one of:

- object
- array
- string
- number
- true
- false
- null

(see the start of sections *2. JSON Grammar*, and *3. Values*)

Older JSON specs ([RFC 4627](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627), obsoleted) only allowed the top-level element to be an object or an array.